# How to refer to itself in the list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, self-reference

```
list_a = [2, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8, 5]
```

list comprehension is very useful.

```
list_b = [a**2 for a in list_a]
```

I want to know how to write a self-reference in the list comprehension.

For example:

```
list_c = [a**2 if i == 0 else a*2 + (itself[i-1]) for i, a in enumurate(list_a)]
```

how to write the part of `itself[i-1]`?

Comment: What is `itself` supposed to be a reference to? The as-yet uncompleted list comprehension…?!

Comment: What makes you think that this is possible?

Comment: @deceze `list_c` I guess..

Comment: You cannot refer to things that **do not exist** yet. And `list_c` does not exist inside the list-comprehension that *creates it*. You have to go with a for-loop here or find a mathematical way to re-write your comprehension that only references objects that exist

Comment: People are mocking this question but it is perfectly reasonable, and I would go so far as to say that Python *should* allow self-referential list comprehensions-I'm sure there are reasons why this isn't supported, but a priori this seems like a perfectly reasonable feature to have in a language (Haskell, for example, supports this...). 


The snarky comments are unwarranted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List comprehension is meant to be a compact expression for the most straightforward use cases. You cannot reference the list itself in list comprehension, for that just use a regular for-loop:

```
list_c = []
for i, a in enumerate(list_a):
    if i == 0:
        list_c.append(a ** 2)
    else:
        list_c.append(a * 2 + list_c[i-1])
```

You can also rewrite that loop in a more efficient way:

```
list_a_iterator = iter(list_a)
list_c = [next(list_a_iterator) ** 2]  # May raise StopIteration if list_a is empty
for item in list_a_iterator:
    list_c.append(item * 2 + list_c[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference a list before it is created. However, you can use this hacky `reduce` approach if you desperately want a one-liner:

```
list_c = reduce(lambda lst, a: lst + [lst[-1] + a**2], list_a, [0])[1:]
```

And in Python > 3.2, you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate
list_c = list(accumulate(a**2 for a in list_a))
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know itertools. I will try to learn this library.

Comment: Well, you can't reference it before it is created, but it is created at the *start* of the list comprehension. I'm even able to actually reference it and use it *during* the list comprehension. Implementing the OP's desired list comp: https://repl.it/repls/NoxiousWordyBracket#main.py (Yes, of course I know it's absolutely awful, just having some fun and making some point :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can access `list_a` from your comprehension:

```
[a**2 if i == 0 else a*2 + list_a[i-1]**2 if i == 1 else a*2 + list_a[i-1]*2 for i, a in enumerate(list_a)]
```